# AxesLabel -> Automatic behave strange

Tags: plotting, regions

MMA version 11.3 & 12.1

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[{x + y >= z, x + z >= y, y + z >= x, 0 < x < 1, 
0 < y < 1, 0 < z < 1}, {x, y, z}], AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
Axes -> True]
```

gives out this strange image.

[image]

Meanwhile,

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

gives (notice that "x")

[image]

So why is this?

---

When I type `PlotLabel->` , this pop out

[image]

So I find this question.

Answer (score 2):

`AxesLabel->Automatic` works by taking the variables you specify and using those as your axis labels.  So in your example with `Plot`, it saw that you're using the variable `x`, so it used that as a label.  However in your `Region`, there are no variables you're using (there are variables in your `ImplicitRegion`, but the `Region can't see them).

In order to get the axis labels you expect, the documentation for `Region` seems to always just list out the labels explicitly, e.g. `Region[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}}], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> y]`